# Mapping multiple foreign key/navigation properties to single collection navigation property - is this possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

Consider the following Entity Framework Core 6.0 model classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? PrimaryAddressId { get; set; }
    public Address? PrimaryAddress { get; set; }

    public int? SecondaryAddressId { get; set; }
    public Address? SecondaryAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Person> People { get; set; } = new();
}
```

From a functionality perspective, I want to be able to load an `Address` with any and all `People` related to that `Address`, and each `Person` will have at least one primary `Address`.

Does Entity Framework support mapping multiple foreign key/reference navigation properties in one model class to a single collection navigation property in another? If so, how is that expressed?

Comment: When a `Person` has at least one primary `Address`, why is the property `PrimaryAddressId` marked as nullable?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it up using multiple collection properties on `Address`:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    public int PrimaryAddressId { get; set; }
    public Address PrimaryAddress { get; set; }

    public int? SecondaryAddressId { get; set; }
    public Address? SecondaryAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Person> PrimaryPeopleAddresses { get; set; } = new();
    public List<Person> SecondaryPeopleAddresses { get; set; } = new();
}
```

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .HasOne(person => person.PrimaryAddress)
        .WithMany(a => a.PrimaryPeopleAddresses);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .HasOne(person => person.SecondaryAddress)
        .WithMany(a => a.SecondaryPeopleAddresses);
}
```

Also since primary address is required it should not be marked as nullable.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to have one navigation collection in one entity (`Address.People`) which is mapped to multiple navigation properties in the other entity (`Person.PrimaryAddress` and `Person.SecondaryAddress`). You can try setting this up in your `OnModelCreating()` method like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Address>()
        .HasMany<Person>(p => p.People)
        .WithOne(p => p.PrimaryAddress)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.PrimaryAddressId);

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Address>()
        .HasMany<Person>(p => p.People)
        .WithOne(p => p.SecondaryAddress)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.SecondaryAddressId);
    
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Person>()
        .HasOne<Address>(p => p.PrimaryAddress)
        .WithMany(p => p.People)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.PrimaryAddressId);

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Person>()
        .HasOne<Address>(p =>p.SecondaryAddress)
        .WithMany(p => p.People)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.SecondaryAddressId);
}
```

However, this will result in an exception eventually:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a relationship between 'Address.People' and 'Person.SecondaryAddress' because a relationship already exists between 'Address.People' and 'Person.PrimaryAddress'. Navigations can only participate in a single relationship. If you want to override an existing relationship call 'Ignore' on the navigation 'Person.SecondaryAddress' first in 'OnModelCreating'